# Sending and reading ASCII values in pySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

I am trying to communicating with a scale that does communication in ASCII format using python and pySerial. I have no experience how ever using ASCII format. So I have basic questions. 
How would I send a a character T for example using pySerial and terminate it with CRLF using ASCII format? 
I tried

```
 myserialport.write('TCRLF')
 myserialport.write('T\r\n')
 myserialport.write('T\n\r')
```

I am also trying to read data from the scale which I would expect to be in a form of '208.01 g' for example. But when I use

```
myserialport.read(10)
```

or

```
myserialport.readline(10)
```

I get this from the scale

```
]ëýýÿ]W
ÿ]u_u]ÿ]uÕ
ýWýWë]uÝõW
ÿ½õÿ½WW]Ýý
WýW]Wÿ½ÿ×ë
```

From googling it seems as pySerial should receive data in ASCII format by default, and send it as well...but I am lost as to why its not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: most likely is that you have the speed (baud rate) wrong

Comment: Both the scale and the pySerial are set to 9600. I that that was the issue at first as well so I tried 2400 but no luck

Comment: Check it works from hyperterm and that you have the speed/bits/stop/parity settings correct

Comment: Got a new cable. Now I can send and read data from the scale, via hyperterminal. but no luck with pyserial. I tried sending it using this command myserialport.write('T\r\n') but get not response from scale.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is the right way to send a character with CRLF to a serial port:

```
myserialport.write('T\r\n')
```

Regarding messy response - make sure that you set the baudrate, the number of data bits, stop bits and parity bits correctly. You can find the required values in the scale's datasheet.

For example:

```
from serial import Serial, SEVENBITS, STOPBITS_ONE, PARITY_EVEN
myserialport = Serial('/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, bytesize=SEVENBITS, parity=PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE)
```

Comment: since they are prinitng extended ascii chars, my guess is they have the number of data/stop bits wrong

Comment: Hmm Thanks. I will double check that stop bits and paratiy bits are correctly set. Right now I have it as   serial.Serial(portnum,9600,bytesize=8,parity='N',stopbits=1,timeout=5) and scale set to same settings. If I cant get it to work then it might be a hardware or software issue with the scale.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was ground connection on USB to Serial Converter (Pin 7 needed to be grounded). If you have same issue, check your pin out. (Fisher Scintific scales use Pin 7 as ground, which is not normal as pin 5 is ground...odd...) Thanks all.